# Responding to reviewer comment

Tags: publications, research-process, peer-review

One of my research articles was in review and the reviewer has given a comment which is as follows:

> "Thus this paper provides some useful information on the most appropriate approach to use when dealing with prediction, even if reported results are related to just one dataset, and the
>   authors haven't provided any comment on the extension of the reported
>   results to other similar cases."

A brief about my work is that I used a dataset from the industry that I am working and developed a model for a prediction problem. There is only a single dataset that the company has. In this work, multiple methods were tried including the conventional ones. 
How do I respond to this comment? Can I tell that this is one of the possible future work that can be done?

Answer (score 4):

You could try and mention, explicitly, that further applications are the subject of further research - but in a similar paper that I had published (with a similar comment from a reviewer), I provided a couple of specific examples of other similar applications where the model could be applied.

A colleague noted that this made it a bit more likely that the paper would be cited, due to other authors relating to the comment relating to potential further work.